# How to change hosts file in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, internet

How to change hosts file in Vista?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type

```
notepad %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

into the search box in the start menu and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Admin privileges, the right file from the start and it even gets created if it doesn't exist (after a prompt by Notepad).

The keystroke saved for not needing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> gets lost for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, though. So yes, it's way more cumbersome to do in Vista than in XP.

I think I may have wasted ... let me check ... 0 seconds on that this year. Nice :-)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't easy like at XP.

- Start -> All Programs -> Accessories
- Run "Notepad" as administrator
- Click on File -> Open
- Go to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
- Change the file filter to "All Files (*.*)"
- Open "hosts" file
- Make changes and save.
- Done

Comment: That's exactly the same as in XP, sans 2 words.

Comment: Well, if one takes the convoluted way, it looks like a really horrible procedure :-)

Comment: Difference is that in XP users run as administrator by default, so you don't need all the extra work to run notepad as administrator

Comment: That's the two words difference, yes :-)

Comment: @davr; You mean a right click? Truly vista is the spawn of the devil itself.

Comment: @phoshi: well, it *is* a Microsoft product...

Answer (score 0):

Another useful software to edit hosts file : [HOSTSMAN](http://www.abelhadigital.com/2008/07/hostsman-3157-released.html)